# Moving checked items to the top after unchecking all items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I implemented a solution, moving checked items to top of list, using

[Keep checked items at top of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746913/keep-checked-items-at-top-of-list)

Now, I have an anchor to uncheck all items in the list. The items are unchecked once we click the anchor tag. But the items are not sorting. It should default to first displayed list, as in html list:

```
var list = $("ul"),
    origOrder = list.children();

list.on("click", ":checkbox", function () {
    var i, checked = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (i = 0; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
        if (origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
            checked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
        } else {
            unchecked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
        }
    }
    list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
});
```

The demo of the scenario can be found here
http://jsfiddle.net/RPN3x/

Comment: Man, I really hate these type of automatic re-ordering lists. The user is forced to re-scan the entire list every time they click an element to see what the new order is. From a UI point of view, I've never seen such a feature implemented that I actually liked using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**in JS**

```
      var list = $("ul");
var html=$("ul").html();
    sortItems(list);       
    var anch = $('#clear');
list.on('click',"a",function(){   
    var list = $("ul"); //$(this).parents().eq(0).find(':checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
  $("ul").html(html);  
                             sortItems(list);
});
function sortItems(list){
     origOrder = list.children();
    list.on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
        var i, checked = document.createDocumentFragment(),
            unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (i = 2; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
            if (origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
                checked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            } else {
                unchecked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
            }
        }
        list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
    });
}
```

see **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/RPN3x/9/)**

Comment: Can we make the checked items in sorted order?

Comment: they are sort when you checked it

Comment: If there are two more checkboxes with our and ours, if we check one first and the Our,Ours,the sorting is not happening fine. Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/RPN3x/21/

Comment: mention in new question  then it think i will better and id must be unique