# Sorting the checked items which are on top of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

With the help of [Moving checked items to the top after unchecking all items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379378/moving-checked-items-to-the-top-after-unchecking-all-items) I have implemented moving of checked items to the top.If unique alphabets are there the sorting is rendering fine.But, if we have two or more options having same alphabet, the sorting is not rendering fine .If we click our and ours after one, it is sorting but Five is still in the last element which is not sorted.I tried to get the content and used jquery sort function to sort it.But it doesn't helped me.

Comment: Demo can be found in http://jsfiddle.net/RPN3x/22/

Comment: What do you mean by "same alphabet" ? What behaviour do you expect ?

Comment: on clicking five after checking our and ours, the five should come after four instead of after our and ours options

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I see from your example fiddle : your checkboxes are sorted by their checked status, and if two checkboxes have the same checked status, their relative ordering is the same as their initial ordering.

Initially, `Five` is at the end of your list, so it will always be sorted *after* all other nodes (with respect to its checked status).

You seem to want to see `Five` appear *before* `Our` or `Ours` : why don't you fix the order in the initial html ?