# Bring checked checkboxes on top of the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

[image]

On clicking a radio button, an Ajax request is send and the Div with checkbox[employee] is returned.

I want the checked checkboxes to come on top.
Was thinking, if there could be some index attribute which I can change dynamically.

Comment: please provide your codes and make your question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following demo will help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/scSYV/2/

```
var list = $("ul"),
    origOrder = list.children();

list.on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
    var i, checked = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (i = 0; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
        if (origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
            checked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
        } else {
            unchecked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
        }
    }
    list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
});
```

Comment: Thanks bruh! You're good at this!

Comment: just copy and paste the answer from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746913/keep-checked-items-at-top-of-list]
you should google first to get the answer, that is why you get the down vote

Answer (score 1):

You can use the prepend Function to redraw the div containing your checkboxes. Use a function

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < checkboxesToCheck;i++)
{
if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) 
    $("#checkbox").prependTo("#container");
else
    $("#checkbox").appendTo("#container");
}
```

Comment: Nice! Prepend useful function! Thanks! Can't Vote up. Less reputation :P

Comment: Thanks. It is not the final code for sure but you get the picture. Good luck