# How to show already checked items on top in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, checkbox

Here I have a array of emails and checked emails in object, on the basis of that I am showing checked emails in list. My question is How can we show checked emails on top on the basis of emails which I have in object.

e.g:

`checkedEmails = {"demo1@yopmail.com": true,"demo4@yopmail.com": true,"demo5@yopmail.com": true}`

and list of emails `emails = [{"name": "demo1","email":"demo1@yopmail.com"},{"name": "demo3","email":"demo3@yopmail.com"}, {"name": "demo5","email":"demo5@yopmail.com"}, {"name": "demo2","email":"demo2@yopmail.com"}, {"name": "demo1","email":"demo1@yopmail.com"}, {"name": "demo6","email":"demo6@yopmail.com"}]`

```js
<div className="form-check">
  {
   emails && emails.length > 0 && emails.map((item, key) => {
     return (
         <div className="myr-list" key={key}>
         <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked={checkedEmails[item.email] ? true : false} name={item.email} onChange={props.onInputChange}/>
         <label className="form-check-label">
             {item.name}{" "}
         </label>
         </div>
      )
   })
 }
</div>
```

currently I am showing checked list by using above code but the problem is I am unable to sort or show already checked emails on top.
Can anyone know how can we achieve this in Reactjs. I have gone through [this vanilla js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746913/keep-checked-items-at-top-of-list) answer but it doesn't fit in my case.
Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a couple of array with one keeping checked emails while another unchecked.

Then show checked on the top and unchecked under it like what you have do.

So, I think your problem is how to get this couple array and it's a simple algo problem.

```js
const checkedEmailsList = Object.keys(checkedEmails)

const checked = [], unchecked = []

emails.forEach((item, idx) => {
  checkedEmailsList.includes(item.email) ? checked.push(item) : unchecked.push(item)
})
```

Is this your real problem?

Comment: Yes your are right but after doing this how should I combine both and display in single list? Or should I display first checked item list then unchecked items list, (In two list)?

Comment: It ups to you. You can try both and think which is better or what's the difference between them. In fact, both of them can meet your needs.

Comment: okay currently I am showing two different list but it is possible to you to show in single list? because if you can share by combining two list and show checked items on top then it can reduce my code as well.
Thanks :)

Comment: It's not a problem. The only thing you should be aware of is that if you want show the items with only one array. It's necessary for you or your code to know which items is checked. To do this, you have many solutions. For example, you can add a property for each item to identify if it's checked, besides you can also only use a variable to record the index where the items before it are checked and unchecked after it. In my opition, it's not always a good thing to use less code to realize a feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to sort an array of objects, basis another object I would suggest to write custom sort function.

```
const checkedEmails = {"demo1@yopmail.com": true,"demo4@yopmail.com": true,"demo5@yopmail.com": true};

let emails = [{"name": "demo1","email":"demo1@yopmail.com"},{"name": "demo3","email":"demo3@yopmail.com"}, {"name": "demo5","email":"demo5@yopmail.com"}, {"name": "demo2","email":"demo2@yopmail.com"}, {"name": "demo1","email":"demo1@yopmail.com"}, {"name": "demo6","email":"demo6@yopmail.com"}];
```

To sort emails array by the checked status:

```
emails.sort((e1, e2) => {
    const e1Checked = checkedEmails[e1.email] || false;
    const e2Checked = checkedEmails[e2.email] || false;


    if (e1Checked && !e2Checked) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    if (!e1Checked && e2Checked) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

To also group similar emails together, you can sort emails array first basis email value like this and then sort by checked status:

```
emails.sort((e1, e2) => {
    if(e1.email < e2.email) {
        return -1;
    }
    if(e1.email > e2.email) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also manage with single array

```js
emails = [
  { name: "demo1", email: "demo1@yopmail.com", checked: false },
  { name: "demo3", email: "demo3@yopmail.com", checked: false },
  { name: "demo5", email: "demo5@yopmail.com", checked: false },
];

onInputChange = (index) => {
    const checkedEmail = email.splice(index, 1)[0];
    checkedEmail['checked'] = true;
    email.unshift(checkedEmail);
}

<div>
  {emails.length > 0 &&
    emails.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <div className="myr-list" key={index}>
          <input
            className="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            checked={item.checked}
            name={item.email}
            onChange={(index) => props.onInputChange(index)}
          />
          <label className="form-check-label">{item.name}</label>
        </div>
      );
    })}
</div>
```

Now you can sort with single array.